# Why does Evince for Windows look so much cleaner than the Linux version?

Tags: windows, linux, evince

To be more specific, I would like Evince in Linux to open chapters to books without opening all of the sub-sections in those chapters as well. By hitting the right arrow key, Evince in Windows opens only a Chapter and all sub-sections stay closed. How can I get this same functionality in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You say "Linux", but you might be looking at two entirely different versions of Evince, depending on which "Linux" you're using. The name and exact version number of your Linux distro would help. Chances are good that simply using the latest stable version of Evince on Linux will resolve the issue. Evince, and all GNOME programs, have been rapidly changing of late due to the release of a new major version of GNOME (GNOME 3). If you are running a pre-GNOME3 distro, in particular, it will have very old versions of packages.